# Standardization on production dataset

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, scikit-learn, standardization, data-preprocessing

Say I trained a Logistic regression model on a training dataset (sample = 2000), using Standardization. I than test the model on a test dataset (sample = 400) using the Standardization parameter learned from training. The result are good, obtaining roughly the same performance metrics as the training.

I then deploy the model on a production dataset (sample = 30 000). When using the same standardization parameters as the training, I get rather bad performance on the ones that I can evaluate. On the contrary, when using standardization parameter from the whole production dataset, I get good performance.

I know this goes at the opposite of ML basics, as you should always used parameters from training. Am I missing something here ? Can I use standardization parameters from the production dataset ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Might it be the case that the covariates have drifted?

Comment: Related to that, how much different are the mean/std values for the two datasets?

Comment: Yes I think you diagnosed it right, the covariates might have shifted. I am going to monitor the drifting so I can apply weighting on covariates. Thank you !